# Indexed tableView with Array of Unknown Contents?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create an index for my tableView `songsTable` with the quick-jump index on the right.  `songsTable` displays the contents of `songsArray`, which shows a list of songs from the user's iPod library:

However, all tutorials that show how to index a tableView already know their contents.  These are the tutorials I've seen so far: [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/), [iPhoneDevCentral](http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/indexed-uitableview-tutorial/), [Innofied](http://innofied.com/indexed-list-in-ios/), among a few others.  They all use NSDictionaries to store their contents, I'm using an NSArray.

I tied to follow the AppCode tutorial and I got stuck at the first hurdle:

```
 -(void)createAlphabetArray
{
    self.alphabetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:26];
    for (int i=0; i< songs.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *firstletter=[[songs objectAtIndex:i]substringToIndex:1];
        if (![self.alphabetArray containsObject:firstletter]) {
            [self.alphabetArray addObject:firstletter];
        }
    }
    [songs sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];   //sorting array in ascending array

    NSLog(@"%@", self.alphabetArray);
}
```

I'm really, really confused and I can't find any other tutorials that are useful for this situation.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

EDIT: I say 'unknown contents' because I don't know what the contents of songsArray is, like the other tutorials, which actually provide the content of the tables.

Comment: songsArray should be a mutable array(reason for exception), why you initialize alphabetArray with capacity 0?

Comment: The "No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'addObject:'" error is trying to tell you that the NSArray class does not even implement a method called addObject: and for good reason. If you go look in the NSArray class documentation, you will not find an instance method called addObject. Read TooManyEduardos answer below. NSArrays are immutable, they cannot change once you set them. You need to use an NSMutableArray if you want to be able to add and remove objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was probably supposed to implement the logic inside loop slightly different:

```
    NSString *firstLetter = [songsArray[i] substringToIndex:1];

    if (![self.alphabetArray containsObject:firstLetter]) {
        [self.alphabetArray addObject:firstLetter];
    }
```

**UPDATE**

This would help you to fix the crash. But I don't still understand what do you mean under **unknown content**. I don't see anything related to this problem in the provided code.

Comment: I get an error ''-[MPConcreteMediaItem substringToIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance', a SIGABRT error on this line -         `NSString *firstletter=[[songs objectAtIndex:i]substringToIndex:1];` :S

Comment: @user3127576, ok, so you're trying to invoke NSString's methods in object of unknown type. Please, don't do this :) If you don't know anything about objects in songsArray you could display no information about them. It's not because all tutorials are bad. Sad but true.

Comment: Ah, it turns out I had to get the title of the song, d'oh!  Thanks for your answer.  NSString *firstletter=[[[songs objectAtIndex:i] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] substringToIndex:1];

Answer (score 2):

You can't add objects to NSArray one by one. You can either add them all in one line, or copy an array to your array.
What you're probably looking for is NSMutableArray instead of NSArray.
This allows you to add objects at will.